# golang websocket

Tags: golang

UI будет общаться с golang бэкендом по WebScoket. С браузера будут приходить разные типы сообщений (разный json). Вопрос как определить какой тип сообщения пришёл, чтобы правильно анмаршалить в нужную структуру на бэке ?

Answer (score 1):

Я реализовал эту задачу следующим образом:

- Любые данные, передаваемые по JSON - это только map
- В любом пакете обязательно присутствует поле, означающее тип
- Выполняю регулярку по определению типа сообщения
- Выполняю unmarshal в необходимую структуру данных

Если будут вопросы - задавайте, буду дополнять ответ

Comment: Думал о мапе. Но проблема в том что уже есть структиры под сообщения. Не хотелось бы держать мап как посредник, тоесть сначало в мап потом уже из мапа в обэкт перекладывать. Как вариант искать в JSON строке msgType и выдёргивать id сообщения и затем перегонять json маршаллером в обьект. Можно ещё к сообщению в начало добавлять msgId типа: 09:{"aa":"ddd"...}

Comment: Возможно передавать в бинарном формате. Например первый байт это номер нужной структуры. Я использовал собственный бинарный протокол, потому что мне нужно еще изображение передавать вместо с json. Кстати никаких лишних конверсий в этом случае делать не надо. Просто правильно раскроить слайс байтов. Довольно чисто получается.

Answer (score 0):

Я решал подобную задачу так:

```
t, message, err := c.ReadMessage()

if bytes.Contains(message, []byte("error")) {
  //Здесь Unmarshall JSON1 
}

if bytes.Contains(message, []byte("msg")) {
  //Здесь Unmarshall JSON2 
}
```

Это при условии, что поля и содержимое разные для разных JSON